# S2S Provenance - Destination penalized

Tags: apache-nifi

I'm trying to use SiteToSiteProvenanceReportingTask and I have set it up like this:

[image]

The destination instance contains only a flow with a FromKDE input port.

However I'm getting the following error:

> SiteToSiteProvenanceReportingTask[id=f6256705-0167-1000-c0ea-0843f4a65948] Error running task SiteToSiteProvenanceReportingTask[id=f6256705-0167-1000-c0ea-0843f4a65948] due to org.apache.nifi.processor.exception.ProcessException: All destination nodes are penalized; will attempt to send data later

Help, please?

Answer (score 1):

If the destination has no component (processor/PG) which can perform work on the incoming flowfiles, it penalizes the incoming connection to discourage it from sending more. If you are trying to debug, add a `LogAttribute` processor to simply process the flowfiles and the error should go away.

If the destination does have components, examine those to see if any are throwing exceptions and penalizing the incoming flowfiles. Resolve these errors to allow the flow to resume.

Comment: The destination has several components, however none of them are throwing any exceptions

Comment: Upvoting, exactly what I was looking for. I also found some good info in this feature proposal from NiFi Developers documentation: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/NIFI/Support+HTTP%28S%29+as+a+transport+mechanism+for+Site-to-Site.